# C# Threading and Memory Leaks

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel, interop

I am writing an application that opens Microsoft Excel through Interop.

The problem I am having is if the application itself Locks Up or Memory Leaks,  my application becomes blocked and will not continue the thread.

I have a parent thread that looks at a directory and writes in a loop for each file

Convert("src.xls","src.pdf",null);   And some times say for example if we give excel a file type it cannot open it will lock up.  Which will lock my thread forcing me to have to kill the process.

```
public static class ExcelConverter
{
    public static bool Convert(string srcFile, string destinationFile, object[] parameters)
    {
        bool bStatus = false;
        Workbook excelWorkBook = null;
        Excel.Application application = null;

        try
        {


        application = new Excel.Application();
        object missingParam = Type.Missing;


            excelWorkBook = application.Workbooks.Open(srcFile);

            if (excelWorkBook != null)
            {
                excelWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, destinationFile);
            }
            bStatus = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            bStatus = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (excelWorkBook != null)
            {
                excelWorkBook.Close(false);
                excelWorkBook = null;
            }

            if (application != null)
            {
                application.Quit();
                application = null;
            }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        return bStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should find out why you have a memory leak, checking and killing your application will not help you in the long term.

Comment: I'd suggest you post some code, so people can tell you where potential problems might lie. We also have no idea what your `ConvertToExcel()` method does, despite you thinking we're telepathic!

Comment: Why have you decide, that memory leaks concern to Excel and not to your code?

Comment: I encountered this issue myself; yes, there are some Excel files which cause the calling interop application to hang indefinitely (on all threads). And yes, the only solution is to perform the conversion in a separate process, and kill it if it takes too long.

Comment: FYI: “Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.” — [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for example if we give excel a file type it cannot open it will lock up

It is probably trying to display a dialog that tells the user about it.  Debug this by setting application.Visible = true so you can actually see the dialog.  Fix it by specifying more arguments in the Open() call.  The Password, Notify and CorruptLoad arguments have an effect.  Screening the files better is an obvious workaround, Excel is really designed to be interactive and chatty about problems.

You don't have too much to fear from threads, Excel is a single-threaded COM object and COM makes sure that the interface methods are called in a thread-safe way.  Which is does in your case by actually creating a *new* thread to give the interop object a safe home.

Answer (score 2):

Here you may want to create an object that extends `MarshalByRefObject` object that you can spawn in a new `AppDomain` to do the conversion. When done, just unload the `AppDomain` and all the memory will be cleared.